# How use case in complex way

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case

I have a new case to add to my query that changes how my sql significantly, and may warrant something with case statements, but I'm not sure how to combine what I'm tempted to do as a union right now as a case statement.  The case tables and concept tables are very large/slow and best to not join them separately/twice.  However, the new query part doesn't need the #tempCMs, or the external_user_data or cm.first/lastName, or cm.user_id. One has queueName and the other doesn't.  Each has a different subject.  Does anyone have ideas on how to combine the queries so as not to hit the slow tables twice?

Here's old part of stored procedure:

```
SELECT distinct
 c.id
 ,uc.id
 ,cm.FIRSTNAME as CM_first
 ,cm.LASTNAME as CM_last
 ,cm.user_id as cm_userid
 ,c.person_id 
 ,eou.external_id--eou.external_id AS CM_ExternalUserId
 ,c.id+' '+' Query1' AS subject 
 ,emd.externalId externalPersonId 
 ,eou.system_id as externalSystemId
 ,'' --no queue passed for this area
FROM
    #tempCMs CM with (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN dbo.CASES c with (NOLOCK)  ON CM.Personid=c.id
    INNER JOIN dbo.UM_CASE uc with (NOLOCK) ON uc.case_id=c.id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.LOS S WITH (NOLOCK) ON S.case_id =  UC.case_id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.LOS_EXTENSION SC WITH (NOLOCK) ON SC.los_id= S.id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.USER u with (NOLOCK) on u.id=cm.user_id --
    INNER JOIN dbo.PERSON op with (NOLOCK) on op.id=c.Person_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.U_MEMBER_CONCEPT MC ON MC.CID = op.cid 
    INNER JOIN dbo.EXTERNAL_USER_DATA eou with (NOLOCK) ON eou.user_id = cm.user_id --
    INNER JOIN dbo.EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA emd with (NOLOCK) ON emd.CID = op.cid
    WHERE     

        u.disable <> 1 --not disabled/inactive user

            AND
            --not external case manager
               (cm.firstname not like '%external%' and cm.lastname not like '%case manager%')

            AND 
            (
                C.ID in (SELECT case_id FROM #CASES where concept_id='501620')
            )
```

Here's new union part:

```
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
 c.id
 ,uc.id
 ,''--cm.FIRSTNAME as CM_first --?
 ,''--cm.LASTNAME as CM_last --?
 ,''--cm.user_id as cm_userid --? 
 ,c.person_id 
 ,'' --not needed for this case
 ,c.id+' '+' Query2' AS subject 
 ,emd.externalId externalPersonId 
 ,''--not needed 
 ,'queueName' AS externalQueue --new admission for this case
FROM
    --#tempCMs CM with (NOLOCK) 
    dbo.CASES c with (NOLOCK)  
    INNER JOIN dbo.UM_CASE uc with (NOLOCK) ON uc.case_id=c.id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.LOS S WITH (NOLOCK) ON S.case_id =  UC.case_id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.LOS_EXTENSION SC WITH (NOLOCK) ON SC.los_id= S.id 
    --INNER JOIN dbo.USER u with (NOLOCK) on u.id=cm.user_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.PERSON op with (NOLOCK) on op.id=c.Person_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.U_MEMBER_CONCEPT MC with (NOLOCK) ON MC.CID = op.cid 
    --INNER JOIN dbo.EXTERNAL_USER_DATA eou with (NOLOCK) ON eou.user_id = cm.user_id --??don't need/cm
    INNER JOIN dbo.EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA emd with (NOLOCK) ON emd.CID = op.cid
    INNER JOIN dbo.UM_SERVICE sv (NOLOCK) ON sv.case_id =  uc.case_id --different here
    WHERE     
            (
                sv.diag_code in (SELECT * FROM dbo.T_CAE1350_diag_codes_Indicator)
            )
            AND --member not already handled
            (
                C.person_ID not in (select person_id from #tempCMs ) 
            )
```

Table setups like this:

```
CASES
id   person_id   

UM_CASE
case_id  

LOS
case_id  id

LOS_EXTENSION
los_id

Person
id    cid

U_MEMBER_CONCEPT
cid

EXTERNAL_USER_DATA
cid   user_id

EXERNAL_Member_data
cid

UM_SERVICE
case_id     diag_code

USER
id  first_name   last_name

CREATE TABLE #tempCMs
(
    CASEID VARCHAR(12),
    Person_id int,
    id VARCHAR(25),
    user_id int,
    LASTNAME VARCHAR(150),
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(150)
)

INSERT INTO #tempCMs(CASEID,Person_id, id, user_id, lastname, firstname)
SELECT case_id,person_id, id, ccv.user_id, u.LAST_NAME, u.FIRST_NAME
FROM dbo.CM_CASES_VIEW ccv
inner join dbo.USER u with (nolock) on ccv.user_id=u.id

CM_CASES_VIEW
user_id   person_id  case_id


SELECT DISTINCT C.ID AS CASE_ID
,mcv.concept_id
,mcv.STR_VALUE
INTO #CASES
FROM 
    dbo.CASES C 
    INNER JOIN dbo.UM_CASE UC (NOLOCK) ON  C.ID = UC.case_id                    
    INNER JOIN dbo.PERSON OP (NOLOCK) ON  C.person_id = OP.ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.U_MEMBER_CONCEPT MCV (NOLOCK) ON OP.CID = MCV.CID
```

I'm not sure what to search for online to answer this question since it's very complex.  Thank you very much for any ideas!

**UPDATE SATURDAY...What do you think? Does this handle the slow tables well, but getting the info into the cte and using it later?

```
;with commonElement_cte as(
SELECT DISTINCT
     c.id
     ,uc.id as ucid
     ,uc.case_id
     ,c.person_id 
     ,c.id+' '+' Query2' AS subject 
     ,emd.externalId externalPersonId 
    FROM
        dbo.CASES c with (NOLOCK)  
        INNER JOIN dbo.UM_CASE uc with (NOLOCK) ON uc.case_id=c.id 
        INNER JOIN dbo.LOS S WITH (NOLOCK) ON S.case_id =  UC.case_id 
        INNER JOIN dbo.LOS_EXTENSION SC WITH (NOLOCK) ON SC.los_id= S.id 
        --INNER JOIN dbo.USER u with (NOLOCK) on u.id=cm.user_id
        INNER JOIN dbo.PERSON op with (NOLOCK) on op.id=c.Person_id
        INNER JOIN dbo.U_MEMBER_CONCEPT MC with (NOLOCK) ON MC.CID = op.cid 
        INNER JOIN dbo.EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA emd with (NOLOCK) ON emd.CID = op.cid
        
)  --common Element cte

select 

    SELECT distinct
     ce.id
     ,ce.ucid
     ,cm.FIRSTNAME as CM_first
     ,cm.LASTNAME as CM_last
     ,cm.user_id as cm_userid
     ,ce.person_id 
     ,ce.external_id--eou.external_id AS CM_ExternalUserId
     ,ce.id+' '+' Query1' AS subject 
     ,ce.externalId externalPersonId 
     ,eou.system_id as externalSystemId
     ,'' --no queue passed for this area
    FROM
        commonElement_cte ce
        INNER JOIN #tempCMs CM on CM.person_ID=ce.person_ID
        INNER JOIN dbo.USER u with (NOLOCK) on u.id=cm.user_id --
        INNER JOIN dbo.EXTERNAL_USER_DATA eou with (NOLOCK) ON eou.user_id = cm.user_id --
        WHERE     
    
            u.disable <> 1 --not disabled/inactive user
    
                AND
                --not external case manager
                   (cm.firstname not like '%external%' and cm.lastname not like '%case manager%')
    
                AND 
                (
                    ce.ID in (SELECT case_id FROM #CASES where concept_id='501620')
                ) 

Here's new union part:

    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT
     ce.id
     ,ce.ucid
     ,''--cm.FIRSTNAME as CM_first --?
     ,''--cm.LASTNAME as CM_last --?
     ,''--cm.user_id as cm_userid --? 
     ,ce.person_id 
     ,'' --not needed for this case
     ,ce.id+' '+' Query2' AS subject 
     ,ce.externalId externalPersonId 
     ,''--not needed 
     ,'queueName' AS externalQueue --new admission for this case
    FROM
        commonElement_cte ce
        INNER JOIN dbo.UM_SERVICE sv (NOLOCK) ON sv.case_id =  ce.case_id --different here
        WHERE     
                (
                    sv.diag_code in (SELECT * FROM dbo.T_CAE1350_diag_codes_Indicator)
                )
                AND --member not already handled
                (
                    ce.person_ID not in (select person_id from #tempCMs ) 
                )
```

Comment: `#tempCMs CM with (NOLOCK) ` This alone tells me that whoever wrote this code has no real understanding of that hint. Your organization should not be splattering code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Comment: But your use of CASE in your descrption seems to confuse the TSQL function (which is a scalar expression) with your business entity of CASE.  Useful suggestions will require more detailed knowledge of your schema and usage. Perhaps you should focus on creating a correct and working query first and then attempt to optimize it?

Comment: sorry about the typo.  Changed case table to cases...I've renamed some table names to make it more clear.  Please do not focus on nolock...focus on the question which is combining the two queries.  The old query definitely works.

Comment: If the old query runs, it means you didn't copy it in to your question... `FROM #tempCMs CM with (NOLOCK) and CM.status in ('1','4')` would give a syntax error; you can't put an `and` there.

Comment: I got rid of the 1/4 part.

Comment: Too many joins.  Have you considered using a denormalized temporary table or, failing that, a Common Table Expression?

Comment: I thought about using a temp table but the dataset is so large that it would take longer to hit the data twice...once to fill the table, once to query it again.  I looked at cte's online, and I'm worried it would take longer like creating a temp table.

Comment: Your code won't work for many reasons:  `WHERE sv.diag_code in (SELECT * FROM...)`  ,  `WHERE AND AND (`  ,

Comment: sorry! typo fixed

Comment: I tried using cte like @RobertHarvey suggested in update. What do you think?

Comment: You are getting a bunch of joins and talk about hitting large table twice.  What is LARGE, CM, UM_Case, etc. Edit your existing post and just drop at the end of it.  Also, in simple English, explain what you are trying to get out of this query.  Many of the tables appear to be lookup tables.  Might be easier option with simple statements of its purpose vs just make this query faster please (not intended to be sarcastic, just to get basic understanding)

Comment: For proper help on SQL performance, you need to share the execution plan, eg via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. And please add what indexes you have on any of the tables, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you inspect the execution plan so you know that's where the slowdown is?

It looks like you're scanning CASES and U_MEMBER_CONCEPT 3 times each.  Once to populate #CASES and once in each of your queries.  How about this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.ID AS CASE_ID
, uc.id
, mcv.concept_id
, mcv.STR_VALUE
, c.person_ID
, op.cid
INTO #CASES
FROM         dbo.CASES C 
  INNER JOIN dbo.UM_CASE UC           ON C.ID = UC.case_id                    
  INNER JOIN dbo.PERSON OP            ON C.person_id = OP.ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.U_MEMBER_CONCEPT MCV ON OP.CID = MCV.CID
```

I recommend adding a `WHERE` clause to that if it is possible.

```
SELECT distinct
  c.case_id
, c.id
, cm.FIRSTNAME as CM_first
, cm.LASTNAME as CM_last
, cm.user_id as cm_userid
, c.person_id 
, eou.external_id--eou.external_id AS CM_ExternalUserId
, c.id+' '+' Query1' AS subject 
, emd.externalId externalPersonId 
, eou.system_id as externalSystemId
, '' --no queue passed for this area
FROM #tempCMs CM
  INNER JOIN #CASES c ON CM.Personid=c.id
  --INNER JOIN dbo.UM_CASE uc with (NOLOCK) ON uc.case_id=c.id 
  INNER JOIN dbo.LOS S WITH (NOLOCK) ON S.case_id =  UC.case_id 
  INNER JOIN dbo.LOS_EXTENSION SC WITH (NOLOCK) ON SC.los_id= S.id 
  INNER JOIN dbo.USER u with (NOLOCK) on u.id=cm.user_id --
  --INNER JOIN dbo.PERSON op with (NOLOCK) on op.id=c.Person_id
  --INNER JOIN dbo.U_MEMBER_CONCEPT MC ON MC.CID = op.cid 
  INNER JOIN dbo.EXTERNAL_USER_DATA eou with (NOLOCK) ON eou.user_id = cm.user_id --
  INNER JOIN dbo.EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA emd with (NOLOCK) ON emd.CID = c.cid

WHERE u.disable <> 1 --not disabled/inactive user
  AND cm.firstname not like '%external%'
    and cm.lastname not like '%case manager%'
  AND C.concept_id='501620' 

UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
  c.case_id
, c.id
, ''--cm.FIRSTNAME as CM_first --?
, ''--cm.LASTNAME as CM_last --?
, ''--cm.user_id as cm_userid --? 
, c.person_id 
, '' --not needed for this case
, c.id+' '+' Query2' AS subject 
, emd.externalId externalPersonId 
, ''--not needed 
, 'queueName' AS externalQueue --new admission for this case

FROM         #CASES c
  --INNER JOIN dbo.UM_CASE uc with (NOLOCK) ON uc.case_id=c.id 
  INNER JOIN dbo.LOS S WITH (NOLOCK) ON S.case_id =  UC.case_id 
  INNER JOIN dbo.LOS_EXTENSION SC WITH (NOLOCK) ON SC.los_id= S.id 
  --INNER JOIN dbo.USER u with (NOLOCK) on u.id=cm.user_id
  --INNER JOIN dbo.PERSON op with (NOLOCK) on op.id=c.Person_id
  --INNER JOIN dbo.U_MEMBER_CONCEPT MC with (NOLOCK) ON MC.CID = op.cid 
  --INNER JOIN dbo.EXTERNAL_USER_DATA eou with (NOLOCK) ON eou.user_id = cm.user_id --??don't need/cm
  INNER JOIN dbo.EXTERNAL_MEMBER_DATA emd with (NOLOCK) ON emd.CID = c.cid
  INNER JOIN dbo.UM_SERVICE sv (NOLOCK) ON sv.case_id =  uc.case_id --different here

WHERE sv.diag_code in (SELECT * FROM dbo.T_CAE1350_diag_codes_Indicator)        --  It is very unlikely this will work.
  AND C.person_ID not in (select person_id from #tempCMs)
```

And don't use `SELECT *`.  Ever.

Comment: Thank you! I like this idea! And good point to not use select *.  I'll try to find a where clause for #cases as well.      :)