# SQL to find which table has diag_code filled, and then look it up in lookup_table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a query and a diag_code is either in one table (UM_SERVICE) or the other (LOS), but I can't join both tables to get diag_code that isn't null, that I can think of.  Does this look ok for finding if diag_code is in one of the tables and lookup table?  It's possible to have both LOS and UM_SERVICE have a diag code on different rows, and they could be different, and both or one could be in the lookup table. I'm not seeing anything in internet search.

Here's a simplified stored procedure:

```
SELECT distinct
      c.id
      ,uc.id
      ,c.person_id 
    FROM dbo.CASES c 
    INNER JOIN dbo.UM_CASE uc with (NOLOCK) ON uc.case_id = c.id 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UM_SERVICE sv (NOLOCK) ON sv.case_id =  omc.case_id 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UM_SERVICE_CERT usc on usc.service_id = sv.id  
    LEFT JOIN dbo.LOS S WITH (NOLOCK) ON S.case_id = UC.case_id 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.LOS_EXTENSION SC WITH (NOLOCK) ON SC.los_id = S.id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.PERSON op with (NOLOCK) on op.id = c.Person_id
    WHERE
        (sv.diag_code is not null and c.case_id = sv.case_id
        or
        s.diag_code is not null and c.case_id = s.case_id)
      and     
        (sv.diag_code is not null and sv.diag_code in (select diag_code from TABLE_LOOKUP)
        or
        s.diag_code is not null and s.diag_code in (select diag_code from TABLE_LOOKUP)
```

```
Table setups like this:

    CASES
    id   person_id   
    
    UM_CASE
    case_id  
    
    LOS
    case_id  id
    
    LOS_EXTENSION
    los_id
    
    Person
    id    cid
    
    UM_SERVICE
    case_id     diag_code

    UM_SERVICE_CERT
    service_id    id

    TABLE_LOOKUP
    diag_code
```

Comment: Please correct your query to remove obvious syntax errors. Lack of FROM clause,using 'omc' alias when no table has been aliased with 'omc'. Likely what you need is to do different searches, one for your search on UM_SERVICE and one for your search on LOS with the two result sets joined together using a UNION operator which will deduplicate the joined result sets for you.

Comment: `NOLOCK` is not a go-faster switch, it's a give-incorrect-results switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have two different searches being run, it is going to be much easier to write/read by writing the searches individually and then bringing your two results sets together using the `UNION` operator. The `UNION` will eliminate duplicates across the two result sets in a similar manner to what your usage of `SELECT DISTINCT` is doing for a single result set.

Like so:

```
/*first part of union performs seach using filter on dbo.UM_SERVICE*/
SELECT 
    c.id
    ,uc.id
    ,c.person_id 
FROM 
    dbo.CASES AS c 
    INNER JOIN dbo.UM_CASE AS uc ON uc.case_id=c.id 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UM_SERVICE AS sv ON sv.case_id =  omc.case_id 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UM_SERVICE_CERT AS usc on usc.service_id=sv.id  
    LEFT JOIN dbo.LOS AS S ON S.case_id =  UC.case_id 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.LOS_EXTENSION AS SC ON SC.los_id= S.id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.PERSON AS op on op.id=c.Person_id
WHERE 
    sv.diag_code in (select diag_code from TABLE_LOOKUP) /*will eliminate null values in sv.diag_code*/
UNION /*deduplicate result sets*/
/*second part of union performs search using filter on dbo.LOS*/
SELECT 
    c.id
    ,uc.id
    ,c.person_id 
FROM 
    dbo.CASES AS c 
    INNER JOIN dbo.UM_CASE AS uc ON uc.case_id=c.id 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UM_SERVICE AS sv ON sv.case_id =  omc.case_id 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UM_SERVICE_CERT AS usc on usc.service_id=sv.id  
    LEFT JOIN dbo.LOS AS S ON S.case_id =  UC.case_id 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.LOS_EXTENSION AS SC ON SC.los_id= S.id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.PERSON AS op on op.id=c.Person_id
WHERE 
    s.diag_code in (select diag_code from TABLE_LOOKUP); /*will eliminate null values in s.diag_code*/
```

Comment: when I combine this with the other 2 times I'm using the cases table and um_case table, and other ones not listed, it duplicates table use too much.  Maybe I should pull the first couple tables into a cte and re-use that instead of using these duplicates.

Comment: For more info on other parts of the query not shown, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68322642/how-use-case-in-complex-way?noredirect=1#comment120767186_68322642